# Loading text file in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egeP2.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KwGK.jpg)

I tried loading a notepad textfile in my jupyter notebook but it has not been successful. I tried including the file path but all to no avail. Please can someone help me out. Thank you

Comment: Could you give us the code?

Comment: Attached is a screenshot of the results obtained

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.